# How can i attach ListView to WPF FlowDocumentReader?

Tags: wpf, listview, flowdocumentreader

I've a listview and i need to attach this listview table into FlowDocumentReader, can any one help me how can i do this one.

Thanks,
@nagaraju.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution...

```
<FlowDocumentReader>
<FlowDocument>
<BlockUIContainer>
<ListView/>
</BlockUIContainer>
</FlowDocument>
</FlowDocumentReader>
```